# Car vibration in 1st gear and no throttle (when moving in traffic jams)

Tags: manual-transmission, vibration, octavia

I have a VAG 1.6TDI 5spd MT octavia. I've often noticed that there is a lot of vibration when moving in 1st gear whenno throttle is added (as in traffic jams or whenever traffic moves really slow). After I add even a bit of throttle, the vibration is gone.
Could this be slipping clutch? I was under the impression that in this case the clutch slipping would be most noticeable in higher gears with no throttle, not in 1st?

Comment: Is the vibration only when engaging the clutch? Or when the clutch if fully engaged?

Comment: When engaged and moving only (or starting to move I suppose, but it's on and off, as in, vibrates for a second, then smooth for .5, then vibrates again, feels like clutch is slipping, but I don't suppose that's it because there are no other obvious symptoms (slipping in high gear, burning smell, slipping under fast accelration), only happens when moving with no throttle (and only in 1st gear).

Comment: I can't tell from your description *exactly*, but it sounds like your clutch has "chidder" in it. You might also be lugging your engine, meaning, if the rpms are too low when engaging the clutch, the engine slows down and can cause a vibration.

Comment: Yes, I have thought about lugging, but I used to have a weaker (though SDI, non turbo) diesel which didn't have this issue so I thought lugging wasn't an option.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by chidder?

Comment: Chidder is a vibration caused when the clutch gets grabby, usually at lower engine speeds at take off. When the engine is revved higher, you don't notice it near as much, as well as when the vehicle is moving. Heat cracks in the flywheel and/or pressure plate can exacerbate it. Aggressive friction material can cause this as well.

Comment: I wouldn't be so quick to rule out lugging - remember pulling away at essentially idle you aren't getting any appreciable boost from the turbo, so at that point it's not stronger than your old SDI. My experience driving some of the VAG CR diesels has very much been that at low speed you need to drive them much more like a petrol engine and give it slight throttle when pulling away or they lug or even stall.

Comment: I mean yeah, I don't believe you're ever supposed to pull away (even with a diesel) at idle, but I don't think this issue happens in higher gears. Will try it again when I get the chance to be sure.

Comment: could be the connector-rubber between the engine + tranny like my 2001 wolfsburg jetta had. WVVortex.com is a great forum for all things VW

Comment: Tested it some more, doesn't happen in second gear. But rpm in second are at least 900 and in 1st it goes as low as 750. Could be the rubber, there was another issue that has since been fixed where there would be vibration under acceleration or when turning left, turned out to be a bad transmission mount. However, this noise remained.

Comment: 750 is very, very low for the 1.6 TDI without balancing shafts.

Comment: 750 is the idle speed and sounds just fine. I guess computer adds some throttle for second gear.